# Alpine Linux: Error relocating libsudo_util.so.0 (sudo doesn't work)

Tags: sudo, alpine-linux

I installed sudo to not having to use root all the time but after setting it up.

```
 Error relocating libsudo_util.so.0: reallocarray: symbol not found
```

I checked /usr/lib/sudo but all the files and symlinks seem to be in their place.

I followed these [two](https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook/0.1a/Working/post-install.html) [tutorials](http://web.ist.utl.pt/joao.leao.guerreiro/post/alpinedocker/#:%7E:text=Alpine%20linux%20is%20being%20used%20as%20a%20base%20for%20many%20docker%20images.&text=Download%20Alpine%20Linux%2C%20burn%20as,alpine%20and%20breeze%20through%20it.) but apparently this is just an error of the file. It's very unusual that a distro provided package just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. I fixed it with this command:

```
apk upgrade musl
```